# Creating column dynamically by checking conditions in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like below:

[image]

Which needs to be checked against the below `master` dataset:

[image]

Here, the condition is to check the associated value for the `Group` and its value from the dataset with the master dataset and pick the `S2SFlag` column value from the master dataset and create an `S2SFlag` column in the dataset. The original dataset is returned by querying the database using `AWS Lambda`.

Also, if post-checking if there is a '`No`' value for any of the `Group` attributes then the Flag for that particular group would be '`No`'. The `expected output` is as below:

[image]

As it can be seen that for the first record in the expected output, S2SFlag for each of the group attributes is `Yes` so the S2SFlag for the first record is '`Yes`' and in the second case it is `No` because one of the values of `Age` has `No` as its S2SFlag.

Attempt so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/siddhesh/Documents/data.csv')

df2 = pd.read_csv('/home/siddhesh/Documents/data1.csv')  # Assuming it as query results

age = df2['Age']
Channel = df2['Channel']
Status = df2['Status']  

df3 = df1[(df1['Attributes'] = str(age))]  

if (age == df3.iloc[0]):
    getS2s = df1['S2SFlag']
    if (getS2s == 'No'):
        df1['S2SFlag'] = 'No'
```

It gives me the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhesh/Downloads/pyspark/src/sample/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    if (age == df3.iloc[0]):
  File "/home/siddhesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 931, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/siddhesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1566, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/home/siddhesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: That's because `df3` is empty. And that's because you have a typo when you assign it, should be `== str(age)`, not `= str(age)`.

Comment: I corrected it but it gives me the same error maybe because of something else now. Can I use some kind of iteration on df column values and get what I want? I am new to Pandas. So any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first create mappings for each group:

```
mapping_Age = df1[df1['Group'] == 'Age'].set_index('Attributes')['S2SFlag'] == 'Yes'
```

In the above line, we filter to keep only `Age` rows and use their `attributes` values as the key of this mapping, but instead of using the `S2SFlag` as the value of this mapping, I changed them from `Yes` to `True` and from `No` to `False` as it's more program-friendly to process boolean values. We will change them back to `Yes/No` later. Note that we need to make sure the same `Attributes` value does not appear twice in any mapping. Otherwise it will report errors in later step. Similarly

```
mapping_Channel = df1[df1['Group'] == 'Channel'].set_index('Attributes')['S2SFlag'] == 'Yes'

mapping_Status = df1[df1['Group'] == 'Status'].set_index('Attributes')['S2SFlag'] == 'Yes'
```

We can then apply the mappings to our data like the following

```
mapped_Age = df2['Age'].astype(str).map(mapping_Age)
mapped_Channel = df2['Channel'].map(mapping_Channel)
mapped_Status = df2['Status'].map(mapping_Status)
```

Note that if `map` cannot find a mapping from (e.g.) `mapping_Age` for a particular value in `df2['Age']`, it will return a `np.nan` instead of a `True/False`, you need to define how to handle this case by appending `.fillna(True)` or `.fillna(False)` at the end of each of them.

Lastly, your final `S2SFlag` is `Yes` (or `True`) only if all are `Yes`s, so

```
df2['S2SFlag'] = (mapped_Age & mapped_Status & mapped_Channel).map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for your detailed answer. But when I tried it gives me output as 'No' only for both the records but according to my expectations it should give 'No' for the second record only since the flag value for `30` is No. What needs to be changed?

Comment: I added `astype` to `mapped_Age = df2['Age'].astype(str).map(mapping_Age)`. Please try again.

Comment: Yes, since I am getting it as a string from the query results as well, casting is needed. Thank you so much though for your answer. I was thinking of applying UDF and all but you made my day :)

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: Just a question, If there is a range mentioned in the master table for `Age` like `20-30` and in the dataset, the value for `Age` is `25`...How do I Check this while mapping?

Comment: then my code won't work. One workaround is to break down the range into individual rows where one row has one `Age` value.

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say something like explode while retaining other column values?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Just FYI. The good thing about exploding it is that it is easier for you to check if an Age shows up multiple times. Obviously if you have a range 20-30 and another range 29-49, then there is an overlap, and you can get rid of that by inspecting `mapping_Age`. I mention about this because exploding ranges is not the only workaround. Another approach would be `pd.merge` plus some conditional checks but that could be way more messy so I would recommend to explode the master table.

Comment: Yeah, I am gonna try to explode the master table only but for now, I just want to check if my age is `not null` or `blank`. So how can I do it considering your code?

Comment: `df2['Age'].isna()` will return you a series of `True/False` where `True` indicates that the corresponding `Age` is null.

Comment: Do I need to change any mapping for this? What I mean to say is irrespective of the value present in the master table, the mapping should return `Yes` if there is some value for `Age`

Comment: use this: `mapped_Age = ~df2['Age'].isna()`. Now the mapping is irrelvant, and it only checks if `Age` is null or not. we use `~` to invert the True/False to make null a `False` (or `No`)

Comment: I replaced `mapped_Age = df2['Age'].astype(str).map(mapping_Age)` with `mapped_Age = ~df2['Age'].isna()` but result is the same

Comment: For the last table in your question, your master table has to have `Lapse` for `Channel` in order to make its `S2SFlag` be `Yes`. However, I do not see that from the master table in your question. Can you check on it? Also, You can actually print out `mapped_Age`, `mapped_Channel`, and `mapped_Status` to see which one is `False` that causes the final `S2SFlag` be `False`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It worked...Thank you so much again for answering my naive questions.

Comment: Again, my pleasure :)

Comment: I am trying to modify your answer by adding one range type column...can you please have a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052625/how-to-map-for-range-values-in-python-pandas

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back late. I am in the Hong Kong time zone. Please check that question for my answer

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much again :)